# How to correct orbit in case of perturbations?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, orbital-maneuver, celestial-mechanics

I predicted the future position of orbital body and sent my spacecraft to that position. But the trajectory of body and spacecraft are changing because of perturbations. So, I need to correct this orbit time to time. How to do it?

Should I find the completely new orbit using Lambert's solver? Or is there a cheaper way to correct the existing orbit?

Comment: "cheaper" in what? Possibilities include propellant, transit time, and computational difficulty.

Comment: I mean computational time

Comment: For i.e. calculate delta V for Hohmann transfer is very cheap but a Lambert computational need to find Newton's root iterative so it bit more expensive.

Comment: I have a lot of spacecrafts and don't want to waste CPU time

Comment: I already solved it in https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/how-to-correct-my-real-orbit-and-turn-it-into-predicted-ideal-orbit

Comment: @Fred As I wrote in previous comment - yes. This is my own answer